# How can I access a variable that is defined within the method in the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, variables

How can I access a variable that is defined within the method in a class?

if I define a variable in a method I can't use it outside the class or in another class

and I am trying to make it an attribute but I can't do that because  it has `self.` in the variable name

and when I try to make it an attribute it gives me an error

Comment: What is the error, please include that in the post along with the code snippet.

Comment: Python doesn't have "attributes". How are you trying to define it? What does your code look like?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo python classes have attributes and methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable defined as `self.xxx` certainly is accessible from outside the class.  That's exactly how "self" works.  Say you have this:

```
class Mine(object):
    def update(self):
        self.xxx = 377

me = Mine()
me.update()
print( me.xxx )
```